# increase screen resolution in ubuntu

Tags: graphics, screen

Today when I turned on my computer Ubuntu had a very low resolution but when i tried to change it said the maximum was 1024x768 (i have a very big moniter) how do i get a higher resolution thnx in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

go to setting >> Hardware >> Display 
and change resolution as per your requirement.[image: system settings]

[image: Display setting]

Comment: One I went there the max was 1024x768 and it said unidenified moniter

Answer (score 0):

Did you install drivers for your GPU? Nvidia/ATI/Intel can be found in Software Updates>Settings>Additional Drivers.

Install the correct driver for your GPU and do some research for your model. Hope this helps!

Comment: I know I have the right drivers since before I had a high resolution then I booted one day and I had low resolution

Comment: Did you install anything particular before that? Or update?

Comment: yes i tried to upgrade to newest version of ubuntu 15.something but some reason it wouldnt upgrade gave me an error forgot what it said.

Comment: Try this: uninstall proprietary drivers, go to nouveau reboot and install proper drivers once again. If hr problem persists I then cannot help you :)